# RxJS: .from is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

**RxJS version: ^6.1.0**

**Code to reproduce:**

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor() {
         this.login$ = new Subject();
    }
    toLogin() {
         this.login$.from(...).subscribe(...)
    }
}
```

**Additional information:**

There were some errors in the browser,when I called this API:
`this.login$.from(...) is not a function`

I found that `from` or `fromPromise` doesn't exit in the node_modules, I want to konw what alternative solution is there?

Answer (score 0):

`from` and `fromPromise` are static methods. You have to use them as follows:

```
from(...).subscribe(...)
```

Not like the following:

```
this.login$.from(...).subscribe(...) // wrong usage
```

Comment: In addition, the `from` and `fromPromise` API does not exist in the node_moudles

Comment: import {from} from 'rxjs';

Comment: @Charles You should be able to locate them node_modules > observable > from.js

Comment: Yes, I find it in the `node_modules > observable > from.js`.
I don't know how to use it .....

Comment: Simply import them like this and use them: import {from, fromPromise} from 'rxjs';

Comment: yes, I get it ! Although I upgraded the version of rxjs, but my thoughts remained in the previous version. And I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy as your issue is solved. If my answer really helped you, please consider accepting it.